# Regression example for one-dimensional input

Tags: regression, example

For some educational purposes, I need a realistic regression example where the input space is one-dimensional, i.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I do not want to use any dummy approaches such as simulation from $\sin$ with some noise.

Are you aware of any publicly available data sets?

Comment: Fisher's Iris data?

Comment: If you want something more interesting: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets simply delete all the features except for one.

Comment: Fisher's Iris is rather on classification. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for referring to kaggle, sounds not bad, but I would need an example where the single component is already known.

Comment: @KarelMacek you can ignore the labels and use, for example, the first column of the Iris data `Sepal.Length` as the dependent variable and any or all of the other three as independent variables.

Comment: Just find *any* regression dataset and delete all but one of the explanatory variables and the outcome variable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For realistic and educational purpose, I may suggest to use Boston data set. It is on [UCI repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/), and popular in both statistics and machine learning community. In addition, it has "reasonable" amount of rows and columns (~500 observations, and 14 variables).

In R, it is included in MASS package. A staring point can be using housing age and value to do the regression. Intuitively, older house is cheaper.

```
d=MASS::Boston
fit=lm(medv~age,d)
plot(d$age,d$medv)
abline(fit)
```

[image]